# Not able to load a color theme from 'init.el' or using 'M-x color-theme-select'

Tags: init-file, themes, colors, load-path

I am trying to get `emacs`(emacs24) to load with another `colortheme` (looking to have a 'dark' theme). In my `init.el` file I have the lines:

```
(eval-after-load "color-theme"
'(progn
 (color-theme-initialize)
 (color-theme-hober)))
```

When I load emacs, nothing changes. I have also tried  ‘M-x color-theme-select’, ‘M-x color-theme-select-hober’, and ‘M-x color-theme-select-robin-hood’ and I have a no match message.

I have also tried to include in my init.el file (eval-after-load "color-theme" '(color-theme-robin-hood)). I am able to include the julia-mode file so the placement of the init.el file seems to be alright. I have seen that there are some installation steps, but do not know if they are needed.

( I have also followed the instructions in [link](https://github.com/bbatsov/solarized-emacs#installation). I have also included in my 'themes' folder various folders to load for a theme, here is my init.el file currently)

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "./")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes")
(require 'julia-mode)
(tool-bar-mode 0)
(menu-bar-mode -1)
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
```

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing [color themes](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorThemes) with [custom themes](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CustomThemes)? It's unfortunate that when Emacs added the latter, years after the former was introduced, it used a similar name. (And it was warned about the possible confusion at the time.) But it did.

Comment: @Drew, that could be it. could you provide some indication of what I should be doing? I put now (eval-after-load "color-theme" '(color-theme-robin-hood))
(require 'color-theme)
   (setq color-theme-is-global t)
   (color-theme-robin-hood), but still I get errors

Comment: That's what the color themes page says to do: `(require 'color-theme)(color-theme-initialize)(color-theme-robin-hood)`, but you need to put `color-theme.el` in your `load-path` first.

Comment: Could you please provide an answer with a minimum working answer and a simple explanation?